# Using RxJs to hydrate model properties async

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs

I have an array of models that I want to map over and fire async operations on them to hydrate a property of that model and then finally subscribe to the original list of models that are now hydrated.

ex. pseudo code. Need some assistance filling in the blanks and/or restructuring the code so it makes more sense

```
var people = [{
    name: 'Jon',
    location: 'New York, NY'
}, {
    name: 'Joe',
    location: null
}, {
    name: 'Tom',
    location: 'San Francisco, CA'
}];


var source = Rx.Observable.from(people);

source.map(function(person){
    // Take current person.location and run it through geolocating service. I also need to throttle() the requests to the geolocating service.
    //ex. 
    geocorder.geocode(person.location).then(function(result){
        person.location = result;
    });

    return person;
})
.map(function(people){
    //Now that model has been updated

    person.save();
})
.subscribe(function(people){
    //Once all the saving of people have completed. Show UI message;
})
```

Comment: When you say you want to throttle calls to the geolocator, what do you mean?  You want to limit the number of simultaneous calls?  You want to limit the number of calls per second?  Something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main trick is to have your promise actually return the modified person and return the promise from your `map` operation.  This gives Rx something it can wait upon to know when the geolocating is finished.

Assuming `person.save()` is synchronous, I see no reason not to call it right after you get your geolocation results.  Here's how you might string it together, using [merge(maxConcurrent)](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/mergeproto.md) to limit the number of simultaneous geolocation requests in flight.

```
source
    .map(function (person) {
        // perform geolocating...
        // return the geolocated person
        // defer the call so that it is not actually performed until
        // merge() subscribes to it.
        return Rx.Observable.defer(function () {
            return geocorder.geocode(person.location).then(function (r) {
                person.location = r;
                person.save(); // any reason not to save here?
                return person;
            });
        });
    })
    .merge(2) // no more than 2 geocode requests outstanding at any given time
    .toArray() // combine the individual people back into an array
    .subscribe(function (people) {
        // do something with the people
    });
```

Comment: That looks perfect. Didn't think about using Defer() in the middle there. What is the purpose of that vs fromPromise()? Ultimately I will want to fire off multiple async property updates from the model not just the geo locating. How much does it change it to do it on multiple properties?

Comment: functions that return promises return "hot" promises.  i.e. the async action is executed when the function is called and the promise lets you know when it is done.  Since you want to throttle the calls to the service, we need a mechanism to prevent the service being called immediately.  So we wrap the call inside a `defer`.  This way it won't get called until something (our `merge` method) subscribes to the `defered` observable.  If you didn't have that requirement, then you could just eliminate the `defer` wrapping.

Comment: for multiple properties, one way would be to just chain the calls with a bunch of `.thens`: `geocode(person).then(function (r) { return svc2(person); })...`

Answer (score 2):

I think [`flatMap` aka `selectMany`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/selectmany.md) can do the job.

```
Rx.Observable.from(people)
.flatMap(function(person){
    return geocorder.geocode(person.location).then(function(result){
        person.location = result;

        person.save();
    });
})
.subscribe(function(people){
    // ...
});
```

[See here](http://jsfiddle.net/erykpiast/7m8zup11/4/)

I guess it's an equivalent for combination of `defer` and `toArray`.

Comment: Yeah but that does not cover the throtteling requirement.